# Analyzing a Markov Chain with both transient and recurrent classes

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I'm doing some self-study and I have encountered a good exercise in understanding how to apply Chapman-Kolmogorov equations to solve various probabilities. Please explain either rigorously or carefully.

A Markov chain $X_{0}, X_{1}, X_{2}$, . . . on the states $\{0$, 1, 2, 3, 4 $\}$ is defined by the transition matrix
$$
\mathrm{P}=\left\{\begin{array}{lllll}
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5}\\
\frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right\}
$$
(a) I know that the chain has three classes, $C_{0}=\{0, 1 \}, C_{1}=\{2, 3 \}, C_{2}=\{4\}$ where $C_{0}$ is transient, and $C_{1}$  and $C_{2}$ are closed, and thus, they're recurrent.

(b) Let $T$ be the time until the chain enters one of the closed classes and define $\mu_{i}=\mathrm{E}[T|X_{0}=i]$ for $i\in C_{0}.$

(1) $\displaystyle \mu_{0}=(\mu_{0}+1)\frac{1}{5}+(\mu_{1}+1)\frac{1}{5}+\frac{3}{5}$

(2) $\displaystyle \mu_{1}=(\mu_{0}+1)\frac{2}{5}+(\mu_{1}+1)\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{5}$

First, I'm asked to explain why the $\mu_{i}$ satisfy the following two equations. I've tried to, but I have yet to understand why they are as they are.
$ \textbf{Please explain this to me}$.

Solving the equations (1) and (2) to obtain $\mu_{0}$ and $\mu_{1}$ only requires simple algebra and I came to the conclusion that $\mu_{0} = \frac{25}{14}$ and $\mu_{1} = \frac{15}{7}$. Again, no idea why.

(c) Let $q_{i}$ be the probability that the chain ends up in state 4 conditional on $X_{0}=i$. Find and explain equations for obtaining $q_{0}$ and $q_{1}$. Solve the equations.

I can see that $q_{0}= P(X_n=4|X_0=0)$, and accordingly $q_{1}= P(X_n=4|X_0=1)$.
The process can enter state 4 only if the previous state was in class $C_0$ or $C_2$ itself, since $C_1$ is closed. I've tried to find an equation to show this, but I seem to get stuck. 
I have to find $P_{04}^n$ and $P_{14}^n$, for sure, but I think I'm missing something by simply assuming that $q_{0}= P_{04}^n$ and $q_{1}= P_{14}^n$. 
If what I'm thinking is right though, is there a faster way to obtain $P_{04}^n$ and $P_{14}^n$ than having to square the initial matrix over and over, and trying to find a pattern for the corresponding entries?

d) Let $s_{ij}$ denote the expected number of visits to states $j=0$ and $j=1$ conditional on $X_{0}=i$. Find and solve equations for determining the $s_{ij}.$

I have no idea what to do here. What's obvious is that the number of visits to state $j=0$ or $j=1$ has to be the number of transitions from $i=0$ and $i=1$ in to state j, since there can't exist any transitions from a recurrent state to a transient one.

Comment: Those equations use conditioning on the first step along with the Markov property and the time-homogeneity. For illustration you can consider a simpler problem like Gambler's ruin. I start with n dollars and I stop when I hit 0 or N dollars. At each step I play a fair game and earn 1 dollar if I win and lose 1 dollar if I lose. For $n \neq 0,N$, my expected number of games is 1/2(expected number of games starting from n-1 dollars) + 1/2(expected number of games starting from n+1 dollars) + 1. The $+1$ is because it takes a game to win or lose a dollar.

Comment: Symbolically we write $E[\tau_A \mid X_0=i]=\sum_j E[\tau_A \mid X_1=j]P[X_1=j \mid X_0=i] = \sum_j (1+E[\tau_A \mid X_0=j]) p_{ij}$, where $\tau_A$ is the time to hit some set $A$. If you understand this then I think you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Thanks man, I investigated the Gambler's ruin problem and it cleared up everything ;)